# HTML5 Video - Add well-positioned buttons (images) as overlay

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have simply included a video:

```
<video preload muted autoplay loop id="sty">
       <source src="content/1/sty.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I want this video to be full-width therefore  I gave the css-properties weight 100% and height 100% to it:

```
* {
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Overflow so that now scrolling is allowed. I simply want to show the video (without scrolling allowed therefore I use overflow hidden). Now I want to add some buttons (and these are [svg] images) as overlay to the video (to like the video, to share the video and to get more informations about the video). The buttons should be at the bottom-left side of the video like the buttons of TikTok:

[image]

But so far I can't get it working neither as overlay nor responsive.

Anyone has a working snippet where three buttons are placed over an video (like in the screenshot) on the left side?

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried already? Your question is about 3 buttons but i don't see anything. Also should the buttons have fixed or absolute positions?

Comment: absolute to the video

Comment: Why don't _you_ make a snippet for a video tag and 3 images and we'll help you fix it to be like screenshot? Anyways your answer is likely to use element styling like `<style=..../>` to set an onscreen position (using `top` and `left` settings) for the div that contains the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit` property to fit the video without overflows:

```
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```